# How practical is it to bruteforce a 10-digit number via URL

Tags: brute-force

Example URL `www.[somewebsite].com/[10_digit_number]`

Getting the correct number loads a page.

I know there would be 10 billion possible digits to choose from, but how long would it take? What are the resources one would need?

Comment: It really depends on how many requests per second you can make and it depends on the server not client. So if the server can do 1000 requests per second which is a lot and more then most websites can do (either big which do not allow or small which are on shared hosting), this gives 9999999999/1000/3600/24 = 115 days. The curl script below would take approx 31 years assuming it can do 10 requests per second.

Comment: This is called Online Brute Force. There is another kind of called Offline Brute Force where you try to determine the plain text of a stolen hash in situations where a rainbow table is not available.

Comment: You will probably be unable to. On average, the brute force will actually take only 5Bn attempts, not 10Bn (or 4.5 if the first digit cannot be zero). However, this will create a terabyte or so of serverside logfiles. This is reasonably likely to fill the disk and crash the server.

Comment: Note that if you have 10000 such pages then it only takes 500k attempts on average.

Comment: Post a URL and let me see how fast I can bruteforce it :)

Comment: Any reasonably designed system will detect and prevent this attack.

Comment: @Navin - You might enjoy [this](http://bsides-2016.pentest-challenge.co.uk/login)

Comment: Just because there are 10 billion possible numbers doesn't mean there is only 1 valid number/URL (unless that's exactly the case you're describing). Take eBay for example. Auction pages are at `eBay.com/itm/[12-digit-number]`.

Comment: @StigHemmer An attacker can take measures to make their requests indistinguishable from legitimate requests. It doesn't take much effort from the attacker before it will be easier to improve the URL schema than to tell the difference between attack and legitimate requests. A reasonably designed system wouldn't be relying on a 10 digit number to keep contents secured in the first place.

Comment: @DewiMorgan You're joking. Surely default installations of Apache/IIS/nginx have log rotation enabled?

Comment: @Rhymoid By time, not size.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**About a day**

If we're lucky: there's no throttling, we can perform each test with a HEAD request, can perform many tests on a single HTTP connection with Keepalive, and can have many concurrent connections.

In that case we're mostly limited by bandwidth. Say we craft a tight request that is 100 bytes, that means we need to send a total of 100 * 10<sup>10</sup> bytes. And lets suppose we have a decent 100 Mbps connection, which will do about 10 megabytes per second. That would take 100,000 seconds - just over a day.

This is best case, in practice there are likely to be issues that prevent it working so fast. We could have multiple systems working simultaneously to make it faster - but at some point we'll overload the server.

Comment: The topic says 'load a page', which implies the actual contents of the page, not only the headers. You math is way off if this is to be the case. We would need to have more info about the actual data to give *any* kind of indication really.

Comment: I think the assumption is a valid page would be the only thing with a valid header, or would have a different header than a bad or missing page.

Comment: @YorickdeWid - It's pretty likely the headers would be different. I have done this in a real pen test (although it was 6 digits not 10) and HEAD requests worked fine.

Comment: This answer is grossly optimistic.

Comment: @Eclipse maybe that's why (s)he says "This is best case, in practice there are likely to be issues that prevent it working so fast" ?

Comment: @DoktorJ So whats the value then?. Anyone can throw around an artificial  number and disclaim any practical relevance.

Comment: @YorickdeWid because it sets a threshold -- it tells you it will take *at least* a day. Sure, in a real world scenario it might take you 3-4 days, but there is now at least a lower limit. You can't define an upper limit, because sure you could run this on a 486 with a 9600bps modem... or you could run it on an ATTiny85 communicating at 2400bps over serial... you *can* make it take as long as you want. Short of throwing enterprise- or government-grade hardware at it though, there will be a lower limit on how much time it takes, and this answer approximates one.

Comment: @Eclipse - It's fair enough you think that, but I'd encourage you to explain WHY you think that, rather than just stating your opinion. My answer is optimistic, but not grossly so. If the server doesn't have throttling, then the other assumptions will usually be met. And I have done this for real with a 6-digit code, so it's not entirely theoretical.

Comment: I would assume 1Gb/s. You can be fairly certain that an attacker will use a VPS with enough bandwidth.

Comment: Good guess and hopefully, ISP and data center don't these HEAD storm as some sort of denial of services attack.

Comment: I think the major issue won't be bandwidth, but how many requests the server AND your machine can effectively handle. In your example, sending requests of 100 bytes to saturate a 10 MBps line would effectively mean 100,000 requests  per second. Even if we assume that a single request would take only 100 ms (so you can do 10 batches per second), that's still 10,000 requests at the same time, and that only goes up with higher response times. You need a beefy machine on both ends to manage that many requests at the same time.

Comment: Isn't the numbers used here worst case? If we don't consider bandwidth and requests per second, the question was how long will it take. On average half the available values need to be checked before getting a hit since best case is getting a hit on first request and worst case is testing all values before getting a hit

Comment: @YorickdeWid Realistically, if you're protecting against an attack, what is the difference between 1 day and a week? This answer gives us a rough *order of magnitude* of the time scale we can expect from an intelligent attacker. It shows that we can't expect it to take an attacker a year or a month, just a few days if the defender is lucky. That's pretty useful information if you're trying to decide how defensible your system is.

Answer (score 6):

Rolling a 10 digit number doesn't lake long on most systems, regardless of the script/language used. The bigger problem here is the number of connections you open simultaneously and the delay between requests. A good configured system will block too many requests that originate from the same address (either by the firewall or the daemon itself).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000}
do
   curl "www.[somewebsite].com/$i" > "${i}_out.txt"
done
```

You might want to thread this.

Comment: The example would connect, perform the request with more headers than needed, and disconnect every time. A better idea is described in the accepted answer, where you just keep streaming tiny requests over one connection (per worker).

Comment: @Rhymoid which is why is was chosen as the answer

Comment: "A good configured system will block too many requests that originate from the same address." It should be noted that this may not be an effective defense, since botnets exist.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on several factors.

Server side

- Server bandwidth
- Does this requested number generate a query on some database ?
- Any firewall/security script to detect this kind of activity and block it
- Any other resources that can be a bottle neck like cpu or memory.
- If you are that kind of lucky people who will try it on a server that logs are stored on a very limited file system, and this kind of activity will consume the every free byte of it making the application stop.

Client side

- Your bandwidth

My considerations regarding this activity:

First do a DNS query, and see if there is more than a server for that address. That will help, more server, more you can split the load.

Test the firewall, get a VPS and make some tests to get an ideia of your environment without blacklisting your ip address. Test some rates, 100, 1000, 10000, per second. Test the average response time for every hour of the day. If the response times changes, so your server has some time windows that receive more traffic/requests and that will be a good time to not stress the server.

With all above results you will know what to do. If the server has more bandwidth that you have, what happens almost all the time, you can get a VPS to help you, choose one near the server. You will have your plan about how many requests will be optimal to archive your solution, for example, if the servers receive more load in the morning, you can use 1000/s during the day, for example 8am to 10pm, and use as many the servers can answer during 10pm to 8am.

**Just be aware that this kind of activity could lead to some services do crash or get a load so big, that it won't be able to answer the users and that can be considered a Denial Of Service attack. It can get you into some trouble because of several factors, I don't know about all countries, in several countries this kind of attack is a crime. Contact the system administrator about your intentions, before you crash any system and become responsible for a downtime.**

Answer (score 3):

**A day is wildly unrealistic**, regardless of resources.

There are 86,400 seconds in a day.  Round up to 100k.  Divide 1B by 100k and you get 10,000 queries per second.  This is somewhat large.  The server will need a decent load balancing story and a fair amount of computing capacity.  For reference, if we have 100 machines with 8 cores each (for a total of 800 cores), we will need to turn around each request in at most [80 ms](https://www.google.com/search?q=1+second+%2F+10000+*+800), which is tight but [not entirely unreasonable](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832).  The client will also need capacity commensurate with that of the server, and assuming you're a black hat attacker, you are probably operating a botnet or something of that nature.

Actually, you have to be operating a botnet, because the client needs to be geographically distributed in such a fashion that the server can load balance it without traversing high-latency network links.  This is critical because the latency between server and client counts towards our 80 ms budget.  If the client is entirely in America but half the server is in Europe, the transatlantic latency will completely ruin our performance, and we will need significantly more capacity to make up for it (or else we will simply have to service all of the requests with the American half of the server, which runs into similar capacity issues).

> But wait!  You said 'regardless of resources.'  Why are you throwing resource numbers at me?

Because the people who operate web services at this scale generally have good enough monitoring to detect a sudden 10k QPS flood of traffic from a botnet.  In all likelihood, your target will determine that you are DDoS attacking them (which is basically what you are doing) and deploy standard mitigations (e.g. serving 503s or CAPTCHAs, black-holing the traffic, etc.).  At this point, your attack will fail or at least take far longer than you planned for, and the authorities will now be working to dismantle your botnet.

So if you want your attack to actually work, you cannot do it at this velocity.  Either your target cannot handle the traffic, or they are smart enough to detect and block it.

Comment: Nice take. One but pick: you've not accounted for threaded/async programming - a single core can handle multiple requests at once

Comment: @paj28: That only helps to the extent that servicing a request involves sleeping (I'm not considering hyperthreading because you can just use logical cores instead of physical cores, if that's more accurate for your performance characteristics).  You may well be sleeping a lot if your serving path is highly I/O-bound, but even with async you will need a lot of capacity to make the math work in that situation.  In particular, the bandwidth of your I/O channel becomes a bottleneck.